# Content of subscript or superscript tag is missing when table header is repeated in print

Tags: html, css, printing

enter image description hereTable head is being repeated in pdf report but the content in superscript and subscript is being shown in only 1st page and doesn't shows up when it is being repeated.

For more details have a look at the images.

[first Page where content in super or subscript tag is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKyq8.png)

[Second Page where content in super or subscript tag is lost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88DBa.png)

Below is the code

```
 <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>SubLayer No</th>
              <th>Top Elevation (ft)</th>
              <th>Bottom Elevation (ft)</th>
              <th>Layer Thickness (ft)</th>
              <th>
                Total Unit Weight (lb/ft<sup>3</sup>)
              </th>
              <th>Void Ratio</th>
              <th>Friction Angle</th>
              <th>
                Cohesion (lb/ft<sup>2</sup>)
              </th>
              <th>
                Constrained Modulus (lb/ft<sup>2</sup>)
              </th>
              <th>Compression Index</th>
              <th>Recompression Index</th>
              <th>OCR</th>
              <th>
                Maximum Past Stress (lb/ft<sup>2</sup>)
              </th>
              <th>Poisson's Ratio</th>
              <th>Dc/Ds</th>
              <th>
                Soil &sigma;<sub>v</sub> at Mid-Layer (lb/ft<sup>2</sup>)
              </th>
              <th>
                Column &sigma;<sub>v</sub> at Mid-Layer (lb/ft<sup>2</sup>)
              </th>
              <th>
                Unit Cell Area (ft<sup>2</sup>)
              </th>
              <th>
                Column Area (ft<sup>2</sup>)
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{subLayersView}</tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Can you please generate a working example. because HTML seems to be correct and your problem can't be guessed.Thanks !

Comment: !!Found out the issue!!

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
 position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

Normalize.css was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using CSS

```
 <style>
        .sup {
        font-size: 60%;
        vertical-align: super; 
        }

 </style>
```